# Query to find those columns in a table where there is no value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

My query is working but it is hard-coded so i have used bind variable so that it can ask value from user but after using bind variable its not working.

```
      SET serveroutput ON;

    VARIABLE v_owner VARCHAR2(14);

            DECLARE
              v_count      NUMBER;
              CURSOR c2
              IS
                SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= '&table_name_in_Capital';
            BEGIN
    :v_owner:='&v_owner';
              FOR r1 IN c2
              LOOP
                EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||') FROM'||:v_owner||'.'||'A' INTO v_count ;
                IF v_count =0 THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line('Column'||' '||r1.column_name||' '||'is'||' '||v_count);
                END IF;
              END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: share your error after that we can help to u... Anyway i have shared some solution.. check it.. if any thing let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS :

```
 DECLARE
              v_count      NUMBER;
              CURSOR c2
              IS
                SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= '&table_name_in_Capital';
            BEGIN
              :v_owner:='&v_owner';
              FOR r1 IN c2
              LOOP
                EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||') FROM '||:v_owner||'.'||'A' INTO v_count ;
                IF v_count =0 THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line('Column'||' '||r1.column_name||' '||'is'||' '||v_count);
                END IF;
              END LOOP;
    END;
/
```

Some Space Problem..

Comment: Yes its working but may i please know what exactly the mistake i was doing since this code seems to be exactly same which i pasted above

Comment: concatenate problem buddy..  near to FROM word. If it is helpful, click up button which is in left side of this answer.